# Python return a var itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a function named `t`

I want `t(n)` to return a variable, not it's value, but the variable itself so I can assign to it. Example:

```
x = 4
y = 4

def t(n):
    if n == 1:
        #return x somehow
    elif n == 2:
        #return y somehow

t(1) = 7

print(x) #outputs 7

t(2) = 6

print(y) #outputs 6
```

Is this even possible in python? Not looking for the reasonable way of doing things (like using dicts), I'm looking for any way that exactly what I said is possible.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: @mypetlion theres not even some sort of hacky way to do it?

Comment: @Qwerty: A hacky way would be to have the variable be a one-element `list` containing the value, not the raw value. If you return the `list`, the caller can then do `whateverwasreturned[0] = newvalue`.

Comment: This appears to be an "X/Y problem".  *Why* do you want to do this, instead of using one of the many ways that languages typical provide for similar functionality?

Comment: @Prune Why I want to do this doesn't matter, I just want to know if it is possible, the exact way I said it.

Comment: @Qwerty Why you want to do it matters because if what you're trying to do is impossible, the Why can help us come up with another solution for you. The only way you can do what you want exactly as you want is to modify the python interpreter. Basically creating your own Python dialect.

Comment: @mypetlion I'm not looking for another solution, as I said at the bottom of my question. If it's not possible, it's simply not possible. Then I'll leave it at that.

Comment: In that case, the answer is to modify the interpreter, fork the language and create your own dialect. You're on the blank pages of the atlas there, so best of luck to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f(x) = y` is a syntax error, so if changing the python parser is out of scope this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Use a dictionary instead:

```
values = dict(x=4, y=4)

def t(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 'x'
    elif n == 2:
        return 'y'

values[t(1)] = 7
print(values['x'])

values[t(2)] = 6
print(values['y'])
```

Comment: I'm not really looking for the reasonable way to do it, I'm just looking to see if theres any sort of way to do exactly what I say, at all, even if hacky.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to the global variable from within the function. This is usually considered bad practice, but it does sort of accomplish what you want.

```
def t(n,a):
    global x,y
    if n == 1: x = a
    elif n == 2: y = a
```

There is no syntax in Python that is similar to what you have tried and accomplishes what you want to do.